# With a OneToMany relation between entities, how create the right queryBuilder with Doctrine (on the Inversed Side entity)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, query-builder

I have these 3 **entities** in my symfony2.6 project:

**Compteurs.php**

```
class Compteurs
{
    /**
     * @var \PointsComptage
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PointsComptage", inversedBy="compteurs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pointscomptage_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $pointsComptage;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ParametresMesure", mappedBy="compteurs")
     */
    private $parametresMesure;
```

**ParametresMesure.php**:

```
class ParametresMesure
{
    /**
     * @var Compteurs
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Compteurs", inversedBy="parametresMesure")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="compteurs_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $compteurs;
```

**PointsComptage.php**

```
class PointsComptage
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Compteurs", mappedBy="pointsComptage")
     */
    private $compteurs;
```

As you can see, the these entites are linked each other.

I created a table for display all `PointsComptage` and datas I need into the table.
This the code for the table in my twig view:

```
  <tbody>
    {% for currentPC in pointsComptage %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ currentPC.ensembles}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentPC.nomPointComptage}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentPC.invariantPointComptage}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentPC.typesEnergie}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentPC.typesComptage}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentPC.consoProduction}}</td>
        <td>
          <a href="{{ path('detailsPointsComptage', {'id': currentPC.id }) }}"><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Détail</button></a>
          <a href="{{ path('modifierPointsComptage', {'id': currentPC.id }) }}"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Modifier</button></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

Of course, for now, all works well. When I click on the **details** button, it redirects me on a new page, where there is another table who displaying all the datas I need for the **current Point Comptage** I choose before (`currentPC.id`).

So this is my controller method for displaying the detail page:

```
public function detailsPointsComptageAction($id)
    {
      $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

      $detailPC = $this->getDoctrine()
                     ->getRepository('MySpaceMyBundle:PointsComptage')
                     ->findOneById($id);

      $compteur = $this->getDoctrine()
                     ->getRepository('MySpaceMyBundle:PointsComptage:Compteurs')
                     ->getCompteursAttributesByPC($id);


        return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:detailsPC.html.twig', array( 'detailsPC' => $detailPC, 'compteurs' => $compteur));
    }
```

To explain briefly: I recover the id of my **currentPC** I cliked on for displaying his detail page, and on his detail page I need to display all **compteurs** associated to the **currentPC** and all the other attributes associated to these compteurs (`ParametreMesure.php`).

So I created a **queryBuilder** for **Compteurs**, in `CompteursRepository.php`, with my `getCompteursAttributesByPC($id)` **method** ($id matches with the `$id` for `PointsComptage.php`).

This is the code for:
**CompteursRepository.php**

```
public function getCompteursAttributesByPC($id)
  {
    $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

    $queryBuilder
      ->select('pm', 'c')
      ->from('MySpaceMyBundle:PointsComptage', 'pc')
      ->from('MySpaceMyBundle:ParametresMesure', 'pm')
      ->leftJoin('MySpaceMyBundle:Compteurs', 'c', 'WITH', 'pm.compteurs = c.id')
      ->where('pc.id = c.pointsComptage ')
      ->andWhere('pc.id = :id')
      ->setParameter('id', $id);

      return $queryBuilder->getQuery()
                          ->getArrayResult();
  }
```

But I have this error with my repository method:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT c0_.id AS id_0,
>   c0_.matricule_compteur AS matricule_compteur_1,
>   c0_.mise_en_service_compteur AS mise_en_service_compteur_2,
>   c0_.mise_hors_service_compteur AS mise_hors_service_compteur_3, p1_.id
>   AS id_4, p1_.code_parametre AS code_parametre_5, p1_.nom_parametre AS
>   nom_parametre_6 FROM points_comptage p2_ LEFT JOIN compteurs c0_ ON
>   (p1_.compteurs_id = c0_.id), parametres_mesure p1_ WHERE p2_.id =
>   c0_.pointscomptage_id AND p2_.id = ?' with params ["1"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'p1_.compteurs_id' in 'on clause'

Someone could explain me how can I recover all the datas I need for the detail page and display them in my detail page?

I hope you understand well what I am trying to do here:
**one** `PointComptage` -> all of his `Compteurs` -> all of the `ParametresMesure` of the `Compteurs` linked to the `PointComptage` I choose first.

---

UPDATE -EDIT

I try with this query following @Jovan Perovic suggestion:

```
public function getCompteursAttributesByPC($id)
{
  $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

  $queryBuilder
    ->select('pc')
    ->addSelect('pm')
    ->addSelect('c')
    ->from('MySpaceMyBundle:Compteurs', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('c.pointsComptage', 'pc')
    ->join('c.parametresMesure', 'pm')
    ->where('c.pointsComptage = :id')
    ->andWhere('c.id = pm.compteurs')
    ->setParameter('id', $id);

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()
                        ->getScalarResult();
}
```

Note that in my queryBuilder I change `getArrayResult()` by `getScalarresult()`, because with a var dump with **getArrayResult** I have this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 5
      'matriculeCompteur' => string 'egfizegilf88' (length=12)
      'miseEnService' => 
        object(DateTime)[638]
          public 'date' => string '2012-05-15 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'miseHorsService' => 
        object(DateTime)[684]
          public 'date' => string '2015-06-19 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'pointsComptage' => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => int 1
          'invariantPointComptage' => string 'invariant 1' (length=11)
          'nomPointComptage' => string 'test 1' (length=6)
          'codeDistribution' => string 'code test 1' (length=11)
          'localisationPointComptage' => string 'local test 1' (length=12)
      'parametresMesure' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 10
      'matriculeCompteur' => string 'ghhh666' (length=7)
      'miseEnService' => 
        object(DateTime)[642]
          public 'date' => string '2015-06-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'miseHorsService' => 
        object(DateTime)[688]
          public 'date' => string '2015-06-19 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'pointsComptage' => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => int 1
          'invariantPointComptage' => string 'invariant 1' (length=11)
          'nomPointComptage' => string 'test 1' (length=6)
          'codeDistribution' => string 'code test 1' (length=11)
          'localisationPointComptage' => string 'local test 1' (length=12)
      'parametresMesure' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
```

As you can see, there are no results for ParametresMesure.

And with **getScalarResult()** I have this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=12)
      'c_id' => int 5
      'c_matriculeCompteur' => string 'egfizegilf88' (length=12)
      'c_miseEnService' => 
        object(DateTime)[638]
          public 'date' => string '2012-05-15 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'c_miseHorsService' => 
        object(DateTime)[692]
          public 'date' => string '2015-06-19 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'pc_id' => int 1
      'pc_invariantPointComptage' => string 'invariant 1' (length=11)
      'pc_nomPointComptage' => string 'test 1' (length=6)
      'pc_codeDistribution' => string 'code test 1' (length=11)
      'pc_localisationPointComptage' => string 'local test 1' (length=12)
      'pm_id' => int 1
      'pm_codeParametre' => string '658' (length=3)
      'pm_nomParametre' => string 'test 658' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=12)
      'c_id' => int 5
      'c_matriculeCompteur' => string 'egfizegilf88' (length=12)
      'c_miseEnService' => 
        object(DateTime)[690]
          public 'date' => string '2012-05-15 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'c_miseHorsService' => 
        object(DateTime)[684]
          public 'date' => string '2015-06-19 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'pc_id' => int 1
      'pc_invariantPointComptage' => string 'invariant 1' (length=11)
      'pc_nomPointComptage' => string 'test 1' (length=6)
      'pc_codeDistribution' => string 'code test 1' (length=11)
      'pc_localisationPointComptage' => string 'local test 1' (length=12)
      'pm_id' => int 3
      'pm_codeParametre' => string 'gjgfjgfj489489' (length=14)
      'pm_nomParametre' => string 'hyhfhfhfhf' (length=10)
  2 => 
    array (size=12)
      'c_id' => int 10
      'c_matriculeCompteur' => string 'ghhh666' (length=7)
      'c_miseEnService' => 
        object(DateTime)[695]
          public 'date' => string '2015-06-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'c_miseHorsService' => 
        object(DateTime)[642]
          public 'date' => string '2015-06-19 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'pc_id' => int 1
      'pc_invariantPointComptage' => string 'invariant 1' (length=11)
      'pc_nomPointComptage' => string 'test 1' (length=6)
      'pc_codeDistribution' => string 'code test 1' (length=11)
      'pc_localisationPointComptage' => string 'local test 1' (length=12)
      'pm_id' => int 7
      'pm_codeParametre' => string 'ygyugyg' (length=7)
      'pm_nomParametre' => string 'bhkighfsighf' (length=12)
```

The difference is that with **getScalarresult()**, my query recover the datas of `ParametresMesure.php` linked to the `Compteurs.php` whereas with **getArrayResult()** not.

My view code and my controller code are still the same, but I have now this error:

> Key "matriculeCompteur" for array with keys "c_id,
>   c_matriculeCompteur, c_miseEnService, c_miseHorsService, pc_id,
>   pc_invariantPointComptage, pc_nomPointComptage, pc_codeDistribution,
>   pc_localisationPointComptage, pm_id, pm_codeParametre,
>   pm_nomParametre" does not exist in
>   MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:detailsPC.html.twig at line
>   41

The line 41 matches with this code: `<td>{{ currentCompteur.matriculeCompteur}}</td>`

As you can understand, `matriculeCompteur` corresponds to `$matriculeCompteur` in my `Compteurs.php` entity.

This is my code for recover all datas linked to the compteurs in relation with the id of PointComptage selected before, then all ParametresMesure linked to these Compteurs:

```
<tbody>
  {% for currentCompteur in compteurs %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ currentCompteur.matriculeCompteur}}</td>
      <td>{{ currentCompteur.miseEnService|date("Y-m-d", "Europe/Paris")}}</td>
      <td>{{ currentCompteur.miseHorsService|date("Y-m-d", "Europe/Paris")}}</td>
      <td class="no-cell-padding">
        <table class="inner-table table stripe row-border order-column display table-bordered table-hover compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td>code for parametresMesure</td>
              <td>code for parametresMesure</td>
              <td>code for parametresMesure</td>
              <td>code for parametresMesure</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Read [How to avoid dangerous doctrine lazy association loading in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/kl7r/how-to-prevent-dangerous-doctrine-lazy-association-loading-in-symfony)

Comment: @BentCoder I understand well the lazy association loading for symfony with doctrine, but I have not find my result yet, see my **UPDATE/EDIT** in my post. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Title is about lazy loading but in the content itself there is an example about how to create a query for 1-N associations. I think the guy is demonstrating how 1-N query can be done when dealing with lazy loading as well. If it doesn't apply to you then you can ignore it, no problem.

Comment: The problem is that effectively I have a One-To-Many relation, and I am trying to make a query on the inversed side of my relation. Thank you for replying me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify multiple `FROM`s, later one will overwrite the previous ones.

So, instead of writing:

```
$queryBuilder
      ->select('pm', 'c')
      ->from('MySpaceMyBundle:PointsComptage', 'pc')
      ->from('MySpaceMyBundle:ParametresMesure', 'pm')
      ->leftJoin('MySpaceMyBundle:Compteurs', 'c', 'WITH', 'pm.compteurs = c.id')
      ->where('pc.id = c.pointsComptage ')
      ->andWhere('pc.id = :id')
      ->setParameter('id', $id);
```

I believe you need something like this:

```
$queryBuilder
      ->select('pc', 'c', 'pm')
      ->from('MySpaceMyBundle:PointsComptage', 'pc')
      ->join('pc.compteurs', 'c')
      ->leftJoin('c.parametresMesure', 'pm')
      ->where('pc.id = :id')
      ->setParameter('id', $id);
```

Since you do not have a direct link from `PointsComptage` to `ParametresMesure`, you first need to join `PointsComptage` with `Compteurs` and then `Compteurs` with `ParametresMesure`.

Just note, I wrote `->join('pc.compteurs', 'c')` but based on your logic you might want to use `leftJoin` instead.

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying me, see my update/edit. With **getScalarResult()** I recover all the datas I need, but in my twig, displayed them returns me an **error**

Answer (score 0):

I choose @Jovan Perovic because it allowed me to find the good answer. This is my code for the queryBuilder I made for find my results:

```
public function getCompteursAttributesByPC($id)
{
  $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

  $queryBuilder
      ->select('c, pm, tu, tp')
      ->from('MySpaceMyBundle:Compteurs', 'c')
      ->leftJoin('c.pointsComptage', 'pc')
      ->leftJoin('c.parametresMesure', 'pm')
      ->leftJoin('pm.typesUnite', 'tu')
      ->leftJoin('pm.typesParametre', 'tp')
      ->where('c.pointsComptage = pc.id')
      ->andWhere('pm.compteurs = c.id')
      ->andWhere('pm.typesUnite = tu.id')
      ->andWhere('pm.typesParametre = tp.id')
      ->andWhere('identity(c.pointsComptage) = :id')
      ->add('orderBy', 'c.miseEnService', 'ASC')
      ->setParameter('id', $id);

      return $queryBuilder->getQuery()
                          ->getResult();
  }
```

and in my twig view:

```
<tbody>
  {% for compteur in arrayCompteur %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ compteur.matriculeCompteur}}</td>
      <td>{{ compteur.miseEnService|date("Y-m-d", "Europe/Paris")}}</td>
      <td>{{ compteur.miseHorsService|date("Y-m-d", "Europe/Paris")}}</td>
      <td>
        <table >
          <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Unité</th>
          </tr>
          {% for parametre in compteur.parametresMesure %}
            <tr>
              <td>
                {{ parametre.codeParametre}}
                {% if parametre.codeParametre is empty %}
                  <em>aucune informations</em>
                {% endif %}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{ parametre.nomParametre}}
                {% if parametre.nomParametre is empty %}
                  <em>aucune informations</em>
                {% endif %}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{ parametre.typesUnite}}
                {% if parametre.typesUnite is empty %}
                  <em>aucune informations</em>
                {% endif %}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{ parametre.typesParametre}}
                {% if parametre.typesParametre is empty %}
                  <em>aucune informations</em>
                {% endif %}
              </td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```